# A RealmObject with no @PrimaryKey cannot be updated

Tags: android, realm

I am currently refactoring some old app and I am trying to migrate from SQLite to Realm. I have used Realm before and I have never encountered problem like this. When I start my app for first time (after installation), I get this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
Process: xx.xxx.xxx.beta.realm, PID: 25947
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A RealmObject with no @PrimaryKey cannot be updated: class xx.xxx.xxx.realm.Vod
   at io.realm.Realm.checkHasPrimaryKey(Realm.java:1184)
   at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:713)
   at xx.xxx.xxx.services.VodService$4.run(VodService.java:232)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My Vod class looks like this and object is properly created, i.e. has value for PrimaryKey and all other fields:

```
public class Vod extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String uuid;

    private String name;
    private Integer lengthMin;
    private Boolean hasTrailer;
    private String description;
    private String originalName;

    //etc...

    //getters & setters
```

This will crash the app. But after that first time (and every next time) everything works fine - with same code and same data. But when I uninstall and reinstall app again, I will also encounter this exception again. 
The part of code in question runs on background thread. If I move it to UI thread, everything works fine even for first time. But I want to parse network responses on background thread and not on UI. Also it isn't specific to Vod class, if I skip data for Vod and start with, for example, User class, then I get "no @PrimaryKey" exception for User class.

Sometimes it also throws this exception:

```
D/REALM: jni: ThrowingException 5, , .
D/REALM: Exception has been throw: File not found: .
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
   Process: xx.xxx.xxx.beta.realm, PID: 28555
   io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: File not found: .
       at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.createNativeWithImplicitTransactions(Native Method)
       at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.<init>(SharedGroup.java:67)
       at io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager.<init>(SharedGroupManager.java:47)
       at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:76)
       at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:126)
       at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:246)
       at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:231)
       at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:114)
       at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:181)
       at xx.xxx.xx.services.RecordingService$9.run(RecordingService.java:317)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

which leads me to think, that there will be some problem with initialization of Realm file? I create it like this:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

  private static Context mContext;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); 

    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    mRealmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(mContext).build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(mRealmConfig);
  }
}
```

and then use this to get instance in thread:

```
Realm localRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone has this type of problem before? I tried to search web for answer, but found nothing useful. Thanks for any help.

(I'm using io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4)

EDIT: I have confirmed (via ADB), that internal storage folder for my app package is removed after uninstall. While checking that, I found out that my files folder in path /data/data//files is empty during first app run. Is that correct behavior? Also, I cannot see anything inside Realm via Stetho.

Steps: 
 1. I uninstall app

2. ADB says cd: /data/data/xx.xxx.xxx.beta.realm: No such file or directory
3. I install and run app again
4. ADB run-as xx.xxx.xxx.beta.realm -> cd files -> ls -> empty
5. Inspect via Stetho, shows no data
6. Wait for minute or so (to give Realm time to create whatever needs)
7. Start network requests and app crashes ("no @PrimaryKey" exception) with first data to parse outside UI thread (parsing on UI works fine)
8. ADB -> files folder -> ls -> I can see everything, default.realm, default.realm.lock, default.realm.log, default.realm.log_a, default.realm.log_b
9. Start app again, everything works fine, I can even see realm data via
   Stetho.

I really hope that I am making some stupid mistake and that everything will be fine at last. Also one more thing, on app start I see this log few times:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$4>
```

I have read this: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1990 and I don't think, that it is related to my problem, but just to be sure.

Comment: I [experienced strange behaviour](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1856) where the Realm store was not deleted on app uninstall - you might be seeing something similar?

Comment: Do you have migration in the app? Doe the service run in the other process?

Comment: I'm using this to handle migration:
`public static Realm buildDatabase()
{
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(MainApplication.getContext()).build();

    try {
        return Realm.getInstance(config);
    } catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e){
        try {
            Realm.deleteRealm(config);
            //Realm file has been deleted.
            return Realm.getInstance(config);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
            //No Realm file to remove.
        }
    }
}`

but it never throws RealmMigrationNeededException

Comment: The exception might be caused by race condition when you are deleting rename (but i am confused that you said the migration is never triggered.). https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded-- try use this one to do the deletion during development.

Comment: Well, I'm not really deleting anything in app. Resp., I uninstall app via phone settings, and this should also delete realm file (or not?). So when I then install new instance, I have clean state and there is no realm file for app to delete and so no need to throw migration exception. But I can add  "deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()" and test it again.

Comment: After uninstall the app, Realm file should be deleted if you create it in the internal storage. Try get in to the adb shell to see what happened. with you configuration shown above, the Realm file should be located in `/data/data/<package name>/files/default.realm`. The whole `/data/data/<package name>` directory should be deleted after uninstallation.

Comment: Yes, I create it in internal storage (default way) and I have checked with ADB and the whole package is removed after uninstall. I have edited main post with additional info.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... From the source code you posted, i didn't see anything wrong you did... Did you using AS 2.0 with instant-run? If instant-run is not the case, can you share your project with us? to help@realm.io . thanks!

Comment: I have finally found out, where was my mistake. As I stated before, this is some old app and I'm not original developer. So yesterday, I found out, that in one activity is function, which is called only on first startup, that deletes whole internal app storage. So realm file was created in MainApplication, then deleted by this function, and when I tried to access it from worker thread, it threw exception. I still don't understand, why it worked without problem on UI and not on worker thread, but at least it works now. Anyway, thanks for you help @beeender , I really appreciate it.

Comment: Great to hear the problem is solved, cheers !

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your imports are messed up. Be sure to be importing `io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey`, and not `androidx.room.PrimaryKey`, which might be a common issue.

Comment: This was it, gotta pay more attention to what I tell my IDE to import. Thanks!